# How does the ManifestEditor get the list of extensions of a plugin?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am currently developing a plug-in that will get the list of every extensions of any given plug-in(s).

My problem is that these information are inside the `plugin.xml` and I have no clue on how to get them without parsing the file.

I've been looking at the Eclipse's Manifest Editor but I can not find how it gets the list of extensions.

To make it short, here is an example of the Manifest Editor with the extension tab selected:

[image]

And I'd like to get a `List<String>` that will hold the names of these extension points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the extensions used by a plugin from the extensions registry using something like:

```java
IExtensionRegistry reg = Platform.getExtensionRegistry();

Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("plugin id");

String id = Long.toString(bundle.getBundleId());
String name = bundle.getSymbolicName();

IContributor contributor = new RegistryContributor(id, name, null, null);

IExtension [] extensions = reg.getExtensions(contributor);
```

Comment: Great! I was using the IExtensionRegistry but I didn't think about the RegistryContributor, thank you very much

Comment: Since the extension registry only works with loaded "Bundles", is it possible to get the extensions of plug-ins that are stored in the current workspace?

Comment: The PDE code used by the Manifest editor can do this but most of the code it uses (such as `PDEExtensionRegistry`) is internal so should not be used.